# Two parts of my java coding are not connected

Tags: java

I'm wondering to call Fibonacci number by using this code but in fact, I want to set the first and second value for Fib number. And in my coding, the input part and the calculations are not connected or it would show errors. Can you help me at least put two parts together.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q1 {
     static int fib(double n){ 
         int f[] = new int[(int) (n + 1)]; 
         int i; 
         int num1 = 0;
        f[0] = num1; 
         if (n > 0) { 
            int num2 = 0;
            f[1] = num2; 
             for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
                 f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]; 
            } 
        } 
        return f[(int) n]; 
    } 
     public static void main(String args[]) {
            
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the first f: ");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter the second f: ");
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter the time period: ");
            double n = scan.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.println(fib(n)); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome *"are not connected or it would show errors"*. What do you mean? What errors?

Comment: when I run the program things I input are not listed in the formulas. whatever the number I input the answer will always be shown as 0.

Comment: Don't use nextDouble as this lead to a lot of unecesseray cat to int, you only need int, use nextInt

Comment: Also, what do you think happens to `num1` and `num2` in main when you call `fib`?

Comment: I really think what I return is not called when I'm calling it. What I return is f[(int) n] and I'm calling fib(n).  But eclipse doesn't allow me to write  System.out.println(f[(int) n]), I force me to create a new variable.

Comment: @Yifei, the answer I gave is running fine and tested in eclipse , could you please add the modified code to the question , if you changed any.

Comment: Why does `fib` have a `double` argument when it uses integer arithmetic entirely?  What would the Fibonacci sequence even mean for a non-integral argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes in the code:

1. Pass the num1 and num2 in the call to fib method:

   ```
   System.out.println(fib(n,num1,num2));
   ```
2. Use these num1 and num2 and assign them to f[0] and f[1]in fib function

   ```
   static int fib(double n, double num1, double num2){ 
        int f[] = new int[(int) (n + 1)]; 
        int i; 
        f[0] = (int)num1; 
        if (n > 0) { 
           f[1] = (int)num2; 
            for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
                f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]; 
           } 
       } 
       return f[(int)n]; 
   }
   ```

Comment: Eclipse still says num1 and num2 cannot be resolved to a variable. It's asking me to initiate num1 and num2 again which is write num1 = 0 and num2 = 0. And btw I didn't downvote, dat was not me.

Comment: I did try the same code in eclipse. Also it was not editing it properly using code {} block. Thanks for formatting it for me!

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I'd recommend you to go over some basics about variables in Java.
Your `fib` function cannot use the `double num1 / num2` as they are defined in `main`. Instead, you initialized **new** `int num1 / num2 = 0` variables within the `fib`, you initialize them with **0** and then you run the fibonacci sum, while actually you are doing **0 + 0** all the time.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't define the value for num1 and num2 in the fib. But the debug section ask me that I have to initiate num1 and num2 for some reason. That the point that confuses me.

Comment: Thats correct. You need to understand what is variable scope. Your question indicates that you need to learn about variables and asking on Stack Overflow such a basic question is a bit off-topic. e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Why does `fib` have a `double` argument when it uses integer arithmetic entirely?

What would the Fibonacci sequence even mean for a non-integral argument?

All those casts and auxiliary variables go away if you use `int`.

```
 static int fib(int n) { 
     int f[] = new int[n + 2]; 
     f[0] = f[1] = 0; 
     for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]; 
     } 
     return f[n];
  }
```

Note also you don't need the explicit `n > 0` test; the `i <= n` in the loop condition takes care of that.

Not shown here - the uses of `double` type in the main routine should also be replace by `int`.  And it's unclear what you expect to do with `num1` and `num2`. They're certainly unrelated to those variables, now non-existent, which were declared and set to zero in `fib`.